# How to read a text file from a custom folder or location with StorageFolder?

Tags: c#, uwp

As you can see in the following image, I have created TextFile1.txt in the Solution Explorer.

[image: text file in solution explorer]

I wrote some text in the text file. When the program is run, I want the text/contents of this file to be displayed in a textbox.

```
using Windows.Storage;

        private async void GetTextFromFile()
        {
            try
            {
                StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                StorageFile textFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("TextFile1.txt");
                string text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(textFile);
                textBox.Text = text.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                textBox.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

My main problem is on the StorageFolder line because it's not targeting the correct folder.

Comment: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` gets path of your assembly. `Path.GetFolderName(...)` gets corresponding folder.

Comment: @AedvaldTseh That's not how things work in an universal app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Universal Apps are limited in what storage locations you can access.

In your case of a text file that is part of the Visual Studio project and has the "Build Action" "Content", you can access the file with an uri using the special `ms-appx` protocol.

```
StorageFile textFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///TextFile1.txt"));
string text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(textFile);
await new MessageDialog(text).ShowAsync();
```

Note that you cannot open this file for writing from your app. It is packaged with the application and considered a part of the application and cannot be changed.